# MATLAB strange error Gamma function numerical integration

Tags: matlab, error-handling, gamma-function

i try to run the following in order to integrate numerically:

```
nu = 8; 
psi=-0.2;
lambda = 1;
git = @(u) tpdf((0 - lambda * skewtdis_inverse(u, nu, psi)), nu);
g(t,i) = integral(git,1e-10,1-1e-10,'AbsTol',1e-16);
```

where tpdf is a matlab function and skewtdis:inverse looks like this:

```
function inv = skewtdis_inverse(u, nu, lambda)
% PURPOSE: returns the inverse cdf at u of Hansen's (1994) 'skewed t' distribution

c = gamma((nu+1)/2)/(sqrt(pi*(nu-2))*gamma(nu/2));
a = 4*lambda*c*((nu-2)/(nu-1));
b = sqrt(1 + 3*lambda^2 - a^2);

if (u<(1-lambda)/2);
inv = (1-lambda)/b*sqrt((nu-2)./nu)*tinv(u/(1-lambda),nu)-a/b;
elseif (u>=(1-lambda)/2);
inv = (1+lambda)/b*sqrt((nu-2)./nu).*tinv(0.5+1/(1+lambda)*(u-(1-lambda)/2),nu)-a/b;
end
```

What i get out is:

Error in skewtdis_inverse (line 6)
c = gamma((nu+1)/2)/(sqrt(pi*(nu-2))*gamma(nu/2));

Output argument "inv" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "F:\Xyz\skewtdis_inverse.m>skewtdis_inverse".

Error in @(u)tpdf((0-lambda*skewtdis_inverse(u,nu,psi)),nu)

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 76)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 89)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

If i , however call the function in thr handle directly there are no Problems:

> > tpdf((0 - lambda * skewtdis_inverse(1e-10, nu, psi)), nu)

ans =

1.4092e-11

> > tpdf((0 - lambda * skewtdis_inverse(1-1e-10, nu, psi)), nu)

ans =

7.0108e-10

Your effort is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `integral` expects the function handle to take a vector input.
In your code, the `if`-statement creates a complication since the condition will evaluate to `true` **only if all elements of `u` satisfy it**.
So, if `u` is a vector that has elements both greater than and less than `(1-lambda)/2`, `inv` will never be assigned.

There are two options:

1. Put the `if`-statement in a `for`-loop and iterate over all of the elements of `u`.
2. Use logical indexes for the assignment.

The second option is faster for large element count and, in my opinion, cleaner:

```
inv = u; % Allocation

IsBelow =  u <  (1-lambda)/2; % Below the threshold
IsAbove =  ~IsBelow         ; % Above the threshold

inv(IsBelow) = (1-lambda)/b*sqrt((nu-2)./nu)*tinv(u(IsBelow)/(1-lambda),nu)-a/b;
inv(IsAbove) = (1+lambda)/b*sqrt((nu-2)./nu)*tinv(0.5+1/(1+lambda)*(u(IsAbove)-(1-lambda)/2),nu)-a/b;
```

Comment: You, Sir, have impressive MATLAB knowledge. Thank you very much!